# What is the difference between the KeyCode and KeyData properties on the .NET WinForms key event argument objects?

Tags: .net, winforms, events, event-handling

The two key event argument classes `KeyEventArgs` and `PreviewKeyDownEventArgs` each have two properties, `KeyCode` and `KeyData`, which are both of the enumeration type Keys.

What is the difference between these two properties? Do the values in them ever differ from each other?  If so, when and why?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`KeyCode` is an enumeration that represents all the possible keys on the keyboard.  `KeyData` is the `KeyCode` combined with the modifiers (Ctrl, Alt and/or Shift).

Use `KeyCode` when you don't care about the modifiers, `KeyData` when you do.

Answer (score 9):

The difference that I have observed is that the value in `KeyCode` only holds a `Keys` enumeration value for the key that triggered the current firing of the event.  `KeyData`, on the other hand, will contain a logical OR of the value in `KeyCode` with any modifier keys (CTRL, SHIFT, ALT, etc.) that are held at the time.